# React Universal Webpack App Crashes After ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<App />)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, universal, isomorphic-javascript

I'm new to universal rendering.  I have a wildcard route in express that should catch anything that's not prepended with `/api`.

It looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res){
const location = createLocation(req.url);
const store = configureStore();
match({routes, location}, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error!', err);
    return res.status(500).end('Internal server error');
  }
  if (!renderProps) return res.status(404).end('Not found.');

  const InitialComponent = (

    <div style={{ width: '80%' }}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
  const initialState = store.getState();

 // | | | |                                         | | | |
 // v v v v running this will cause server to crash v v v v

  const componentHTML = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(InitialComponent);

  console.log('Component html? ', componentHTML);
  const html = `

  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <base href="/" />
        <title>rūh collective: server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="react-app">${html}</div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
    `

      res.send(html);

    });
}
```

This successfully sends to the server, because I see that the title has the ruh:server included.

Right after the page loads, the server crashes saying pointing to `events.js:82`

If I comment out the `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` and I remove the reference in the html the server loads and does not crash.

If I run `ReactDOMServer.renderToString` and DO NOT EVEN REFERENCE IT, the server still crashes on load.  Commenting out will allow the server to live.

Here is my webpack config:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const commonLoaders = [
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'react-hot',
  }, {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      stage: 0,
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.jsx$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: {
      stage: 0,
    }
  },
  { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
  {
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]',
  },
  {
    test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    loaders: [
      'file?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
      'image-webpack?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false',
    ]
  }
];

//const assetsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'dist');

module.exports = 
  {
    name: 'browser',
    entry: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './browser/js/main.js',
    ],
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: commonLoaders.concat([
        {test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style!css!sass?sourceMap'},
      ])
    }
  }
```

If I comment out the line `const componentHTML` etc, the server will run, but it's not rendering universally. I can try to replicate the issue if anyone is interested

Comment: I seem to have a similar issue. For me the line with ReactDOMServer.renderToString seems to crash silently without reporting any error. Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: I do not recall. I don't think it was ever solved fully. Sorry. Maybe I should delete the question as it provides no help.

Comment: @shaimo I have same problem. How'd you debug it?

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy it turned out that somehow with renderToString errors are not reported but rather cause a silent exit. To check this try to render some trivial component rather than your actual component and see if it works. My solution was to gradually pinpoint the component whose render function caused the crash. It was a very stupid issue with some missing prop...